# Is `/etc/fstab` used to remount drives?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, fstab

I have a device installed with Ubuntu 14.04.5 which has a single hard drive with  an ext4 file system.

By reading the document [Ext4 Filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt) I learned that the default data mode is `ordered` which only protects the metadata. In my project, we want to change it to `journal` to also protect file data because the data safety is of higher value.

The first thing I tried was to modify the `/etc/fstab` file. I tried to change

```
UUID=<UUID> / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

to

```
UUID=<UUID> / ext4 errors=remount-ro,data=journal 0 1
```

by appending `data=journal` to the option field.

However, when I reboot the device, I ended up with an error message saying `cannot change data mode on remount`. I checked the `dmesg` and saw an earlier message about mounting the drive with `ordered` data mode.

For an embarrassingly long time, I thought `/etc/fstab` is used to override the default mounting options so the drives are only mounted once. But now it looks wrong: the drive is mounted using its default mount options, then `/etc/fstab` is picked up to remount it.

**My questions are**:

- **Is this "mount-remout" process the design of the system?** I read the [`Fstab` wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) but didn't see it mentions the "mount-remount" thing.
- If `/etc/fstab` is truly used for remounting, **in which step of the booting process is the drive mounted for the first time?** Is it implemented in `/etc/init.d`? I did see some scripts in `/etc/init.d` called `umountfs` and `umountroot`, but, skimming their content, they don't look relevant.

Comment: I think it's the "chicken and egg" problem mentioned here (`/etc/fstab` resides on the root filesystem, but it can't be read until after the filesytem has been mounted): [Does initramfs use /etc/fstab?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92739/65304)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### When /etc/fstab is used

If you run `sudo strace -e open,openat mount -o remount,rw /` you will see that the command does in fact open `/etc/fstab`.  This is the most common command you will see, often referenced in articles on working from recovery shell.

To also quote [sourcejedi's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398942/85039) (which comes from `mount(8)` manual):

> mount -o remount,rw  /dir
>
> After this call, **mount reads fstab and merges these options with the options from the command line (-o)**. If no mountpoint is found in fstab, then a remount with unspecified source is allowed.

However, that doesn't mean that `/etc/fstab` is always used. In particular, when you also specify the device file; reference to the [`mount(8)` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount):

> The remount functionality follows the standard way how the mount command works with options from fstab. It means the mount command doesn't read fstab (or mtab) only when a device and dir are fully specified.
>
> mount -o remount,rw /dev/foo /dir
>
> After this call all old mount options are replaced **and arbitrary
>   stuff from fstab is ignored**, except the loop= option which is
>   internally generated and maintained by the mount command.

This makes sense, since `/dir` could be arbitrary - remounting a device to different mountpoint.

The `/etc/fstab` is also not referenced when mounting `/` filesystem at boot time kernel knows nothing of `/etc/fstab`. To quote [psusi's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18055/85039):

> Eventually boot loaders came along and could pass a command line to the kernel. If the root= argument was passed, that told the kernel where the root fs was instead of the built in value. The drivers needed to access that still had to be built into the kernel
>
> ...
>
> Finally, today we have the initramfs. This is similar to the initrd, but instead of being a compressed filesystem image that is loaded into a ramdisk, it is a compressed cpio archive. A tmpfs is mounted as the root, and the archive is extracted there. Instead of using pivot_root, which was regarded as a dirty hack, the initramfs boot scripts mount the real root in /root, delete all files in the tmpfs root, then chroot into /root, and exec /sbin/init

#### Filesystems which don't need fstab

Note also, that Linux kernel has [other filesystems](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-8.html) which reside in memory - these are not available to users normally, some of which do not have a mountpoint at all, while some are exposed to the users. Kernel doesn't have to reference `/etc/fstab` for those. Example of that is `/proc` - it's a virtual filesystem that exposes mostly information about processes, and some stuff about hardware and system that should really be in `/sys` - another virtual filesystem.

Answer (score 9):

From `man ext4`:

```
data={journal|ordered|writeback}
              Specifies the journaling mode for file data.  Metadata is always
              journaled.  To use modes other than ordered on the root filesys‐
              tem, pass the mode to the kernel as boot parameter,  e.g.  root‐
              flags=data=journal.
```

Remove `data=ordered` from your fstab-line and edit `/etc/default/grub` instead.
In `/etc/default/grub` change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash root‐flags=data=journal"
```

run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.